# Ignore specific caracter in a python regex match

Tags: python, regex

I've been trying to extract some values from strings like these:
'5 bucks' and also be able to get '5bucks' but ignore the word bucks when it comes alone without any number in front of it. I've been trying with this regex:

`(\d*)(?:\s?)(?=bucks|dollars)`

and testing on https://regex101.com/. It's giving me two matches instead of one, using the very same string. Why is that? That's what im getting:

Match 1:

Full match: 5

Group 1:    5

Match 2:

Full match:

Group 1:

On the second match it appears to be both empty. Is there a way to prevent my regex on finding these len 0 matches? Or any way i could treat that?

Comment: Do you only want to match the digits? Or the digits and bucks together?

Comment: Digits and bucks together

Comment: You can use `\b\d+ ?(?:bucks|dollars)\b` to get them both https://regex101.com/r/sMwa3y/1 The lookahead `(?=` is a non consuming assertion.

Comment: @FelipeHonorato - Your link does not have any code.

Comment: Dude you have completely solved my problem. Thank you. Post it as an answer so i can close this topic @Thefourthbird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get those matches because you match optional digits `\d*` and an optional whitespace char `\s?` where the positive lookahead assertion it true as bucks or dollars is on the right.

To get both variations, you could use an alternation `|` with a non capturing group. To prevent the words being part of a larger word, you could add word boundaries `\b`

```
\b\d+ ?(?:bucks|dollars)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZmhgtH/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
'(\d+)\s*(bucks|dollars)?'
```

And then pick the first item matched.

Comment: Well but this way i can't have a backspace between the number and the words and i could also put any word there that it would still matches

Comment: @FelipeHonorato - That is an extremely abnormal request.  'Backspace' is normally handled at a very low level during text entry.  It does not survive long enough to show up in a database.

Comment: @FelipeHonorato - `\b` in a regexp is not "backspace"; it is "word boundary".

Comment: Yes i know. The \s is refering to that, not the \b